# Show or Hide table not working without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to edit a web-page that consists of several different menus of which include numerous of tables from top to bottom. To organize this mess, I've planned to hide tables when clicked on an item and found this: [How to hide html div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340108/how-to-hide-html-div) . 
, which works fine on its own. However, after clicking different menu and turning back to the table, I cannot manage to hide the table without refreshing the page.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#show_whatever').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div#disapp').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#table-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#table-scroll {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1070px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>

        <a href="#" class="navigation" id="show_whatever">ODM HMC'den Alınan Profil Bilgileri </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="disapp" class="hidden">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="border:none;">


        <div id="table-wrapper">
          <div id="table-scroll">

            <table>........</table>

          </div>
        </div>

        <table>........</table>

  </table>
</div>
```

Since tables include some irrelevant sql queries, I didn't add into the codes. So, what could be the problem ?

Comment: It would be helpful to reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.net and post the link to it.

Comment: It is a bit hard to reproduce the problem. I cannot basically hide or show the table without refreshing page. @TonyHinkle

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on your fiddle. Though, side-note, you have an excess closing div and table tag at the bottom of your markup.

Comment: @SpYk3HH don't fix broken markup in the code. It may be the reason the code isn't working

Comment: @Turnip: I agree that code should be kept intact aside from indentation fixes, but funnily enough in this case the markup isn't actually broken - it makes no difference whether the </td></tr> end tags are included, they're not strictly necessary and the markup is valid and functionally equivalent either way. The inexplicable changes to the JS, on the other hand...

Comment: @SpYk3HH: Please try to keep the code as pristine as you can when reformatting it. Don't change selector strings (div#disapp -> #disapp), variable names (event -> e), or add/remove tags that don't need to be added/removed. In the case of the selector string you're actually changing its meaning which is a no-no.